# Fast way to check whether properties of one array of objects overlap with properties of another array of objects

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am wondering if there's a better way to do the following:

```
for( customObject *myObject in self.myObjects ) {
    myObjectsDictionary[myObject.objectID] = customObject;
}
```

Basically I have a very long array of custom objects. Each of those objects should have a unique identification number. Therefore just before adding new objects I create a dictionary of the ID numbers so that I can check new proposed ID numbers against these existing ID numbers and eliminate duplicates. This seems inefficient...is there an obvious language feature to do this faster/better?

What comes to mind is sets...that I could make a set of these objectID's and then check the new object's ids against the old. Is that better than the above? If so, why? If not, is there another alternative?

Answer (score 0):

At the broad stroke level, your dictionary solution is equivalent to using an `NSSet`.  The way one might make a real difference in efficiency would be a different algorithm (different than the implicit use of `NSObject`'s `hash` used in both dictionary and set).

For example, tries built on the key ([see here](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/using-tries/)), will scale with key length.  Whether its faster than hash for a given length key is an empirical question.

The important principal to remember is to make reasonable decisions first (dictionary and set are both very reasonable), and don't optimize further unless there's a demonstrated need.

Answer (score 0):

An `NSSet` will have a (small) advantage over an `NSDictionary` as the former only stores the `objectID` reference and the latter stores the `customObject` one as well.

If your `objectID` is actually a boxed (`NSNumber`) or textual (`NSString`) version of an integral type then you can use `CFSet` which can store integers (as `void *`) directly and thus save all the boxing.

The `NS` collections will use the `hash` function defined on whatever type `objectID` is, which can be overidden; `CFSet` uses a default or one supplied at creation. If you are relying on the default hash function and that hash is less optimal for your particular data set then you can consider implementing your own hash function - but only go there if you have a performance issue.

HTH